# Simple form node js application

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a simple form, with user name and last name, and when the user submit information, another page is displayed. I did a form in html, but I'm not sure about what to do next? Does anyone have a small, self-contained example of a form, using `node js`?

Comment: There are lots of examples on github. For example, [look at this one](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This example does not quite complete your task. But it is a self contained node.js program that displays a form and a different page upon form receipt.

Copy it into a file and then run `node filename.js` and then go to `http://localhost:3000` in a browser.

Take note of the asynchronous code structure. I define a `handler` function but don't execute it immediately. We instead pass the function to `http.createServer` and then call `.listen(3000)`. Now when an HTTP request comes in, the http server will pass a `req, res` pair to the handler function. `req` is the request object (this will contain the form data; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js) for some hints on how to get that data out. (I suggest that you jump right in and build a small Express app. It's a really nice framework.)

```
//app.js
// Load the built in 'http' library
var http = require('http'); 
var util = require('util');

// Create a function to handle every HTTP request
function handler(req, res){
  if(req.method == "GET"){ 
    console.log('get');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("<html><body><form action='/' method='post'><input type='text' name='hello'><input type='submit'></form></body></html>");
  } else if(req.method == 'POST'){
    console.log('post');
    // Here you could use a library to extract the form content
    // The Express.js web framework helpfully does just that
    // For simplicity's sake we will always respond with 'hello world' here
    // var hello = req.body.hello;
    var hello = 'world';
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("<html><body><h1>Hello "+hello+"!</h1></body></html>");
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
  };
};

// Create a server that invokes the `handler` function upon receiving a request
// And have that server start listening for HTTP requests
// The callback function is executed at some time in the future, when the server
// is done with its long-running task (setting up the network and port etc)
http.createServer(handler).listen(3000, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error starting http server');
  } else {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
  };
});
```