# Get Node.js to get user's input from a HTML text field?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I've basically been trying to make a simple game where the user can submit their high-score to a Node.js server. I'm just trying to do something very simple but can't seem to find much to help me online!

At the moment I've got the main page to connect and respond to the server using AJAX.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div> 
<h3>Upload your high-score:</h3>
Your score: <input type="text" name="yourScore">
<button id="SubmitBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Here's the JavaScript which triggers when the "Submit" button is clicked and appends the "test" div when successfully connected (Just to show it responds):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#SubmitBtn').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://localhost', 
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        jsonpCallback: "_testcb", 
        cache: false, 
        timeout: 5000, 
        success: function(data) { 
            $("#test").append(data); 
        }, 
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert('Error connecting to the Node.js server... ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

});

And here's my Node.js at the moment where it runs and responds:

```
var http = require('http'); 
console.log('Game server running...'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
console.log('Submit button has been clicked.'); 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
res.end('_testcb(\'{"message": "Welcome! Node.js Responding!"}\')'); 
}).listen(80);
```

So yeah, if anyone knows how I can get my Node.js server to read the data in the "yourScore" text field and when the "SubmitBtn" button has been clicked to send the data to the server, I would be most thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First

You are not sending any data with your AJAX request.

Possible solution (it is better if you get score `input` element using an `ID` or serializing the `form` element):

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://localhost',
    data: { score : $("input[name='score']").val() },
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    jsonpCallback: "_testcb", 
    cache: false, 
    timeout: 5000, 
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#test").append(data); 
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert('Error connecting to the Node.js server... ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown); 
    } 
});
```

### Second

Inside your NodeJS request handler you can get the sent data using the request object.

Possible solution:

```
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      var score = req.body.score;
      console.log(score);
      //do whatever you want
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
      res.end('_testcb(\'{"message": "Welcome! Node.js Responding!"}\')'); 
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however I get an issue when running the Node.js server with the added code you suggested, here's the error:
ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mike\SnakeServer.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @Mike it had a mistake. change `request` to `req`. See my answer again.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but when I change it to "var score = req.body.score;" it says "Cannot read property 'score' of undefined", even though both the "name" and "ID" attributes of the input text field are called "score".. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if you are inside this scope `http.createServer(function (req, res) {});` req.body must be defined. Check your code to see if you are missing something

Comment: are you using connect's bodyParser middleware? You need it to have `request.body` object available. If not you need to parse data yourself using `req.on('data', function(chunk) { } );`

Comment: I'm not using bodyParser middleware no. I've put the 'req.on('data', function(chunk) { req.body = ""; });' in the 'createServer' function, but still getting the same issue, do I need to add any response sections to it? Sorry for all the questions, I'm still pretty new to Node.js

Comment: Do I need First part in order to do Second part or are two different ways to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a POST to the server, check out [this simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762188/simple-form-node-js-application)

in your script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        yourScore: $('input[name="yourScore"]').val()
    }, 
    //other parameters
```

and in your server

```
http.createServer(
   //...
   if (req.method == 'POST'){
      console.log(req.body.yourScore)
```